# PHP html-Mail empty email

Tags: php, email

Hy guys,

I'm trying to send a couple of emails through PHP with the default PHP Mail function ( i know that there are libraries, but this is a script i will only run 1 time... )

Here's the code that i'm using (the `$leMSG` and email sending part are inside an foreach loop ):

```
$leMSG = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor website.nl</tilte></head><body><p>Beste klant van website.nl,</p><p>website.nl is overgegaan naar een nieuw systeem en uw account is mee verhuisd. Helaas konden we niet uw oude wachtwoord gebruiken, aangezien die beveiligd was opgeslagen. Daarom waren wij genoodzaakt om uw wachtwoord te resetten.</p><p>Uw nieuwe gegevens zijn:<br />Email: ' . $leEmail . '<br />Wachtwoord: ' . $password . '</p><p>U kunt uw gegevens <a href="http://wwww,website.nl/index.php?route=account/account"> hier </a> na lopen en desnoods veranderen.</p><p>Mochten er nog vragen / opmerkingen zijn, dan horen wij dat graag.</p><p>Met Vriendelijke Groet,<br />Webbeheer website.nl</p></body></html>';
$this -> mailer($leMSG, $item['email'], $item['customer_id']);
```

And the mailer function:

```
function mailer($msg, $to, $id){
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: email@addres.nl\r\n';
    $headers .= 'From: Webmaster website.nl <webmaster@website.nl> \r\n';

    if(mail('email@addres.nl', 'Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor website.nl', $msg, $headers)){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        echo "<br />ERROR @id_" . $id;
    }
}
```

But the email is empty. When i look at the source ( with GMail ), i can see that there is some HTML:

```
From: webmaster@website.nl 
To:  
Date: Thu, 7 Nov 2013 15:43:29 +0100 
Subject: Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor website.nl 

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor website.nl</tilte></head><body><p>Beste klant van website.nl,</p><p>website.nl is overgegaan naar een nieuw systeem en uw account is mee verhuisd. Helaas konden we niet uw oude wachtwoord gebruiken, aangezien die beveiligd was opgeslagen. Daarom waren wij genoodzaakt om uw wachtwoord te resetten.</p><p>Uw nieuwe gegevens zijn:<br />Email: email@addres.nl<br />Wachtwoord: 55jws2tS0j</p><p>U kunt uw gegevens <a href="http://wwww,website.nl/index.php?route=account/account"> hier </a> na lopen en desnoods veranderen.</p><p>Mochten er nog vragen / opmerkingen zijn, dan horen wij dat graag.</p><p>Met Vriendelijke Groet,<br />Webbeheer website.nl</p></body></html>
```

Does anybody knows what's wrong with this script? I don't get any kind of error or something like that...

**EDIT, Using now some more newlines for code readability, but that didn't fix it**

```
$leMSG = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor Kadobos.nl</tilte></head>' . PHP_EOL;
$leMSG .= '<body><p>Beste klant van website.nl,</p>' . PHP_EOL;
$leMSG .= '<p>website.nl is overgegaan naar een nieuw systeem en uw account is mee verhuisd. Helaas konden we niet uw oude wachtwoord gebruiken, aangezien die beveiligd was opgeslagen. Daarom waren wij genoodzaakt om uw wachtwoord te resetten.</p>' . PHP_EOL;
$leMSG .= '<p>Uw nieuwe gegevens zijn:<br />Email: ' . $leEmail . '<br />Wachtwoord: ' . $password . '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
$leMSG .= '<p>U kunt uw gegevens <a href="http://wwww.website.nl/index.php?route=account/account"> hier </a> na lopen en desnoods veranderen.</p>' . PHP_EOL;
$leMSG .= '<p>Mochten er nog vragen / opmerkingen zijn, dan horen wij dat graag.</p>' . PHP_EOL;
$leMSG .= '<p>Met Vriendelijke Groet,<br />Webbeheer website.nl</p></body></html>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Protip: use line breaks in HTML strings to make them easier to read.

Comment: One thing - you're explicitly setting a `To:` header in `$headers`, which you don't need to; that's taken care of by the first parameter in the call to `mail()`. Try removing that line.

Comment: Don't send html mail with `mail()`. `mail()` is useless garbage. Use a proper mail package, like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, updated my question with the updated code. Thanks for the tip, but it didn't fix it ;)

Comment: @andrewsi, thanks for the tip, but that didn't fix it :S

Comment: @MarcB, i know, but i was hoping to not have to because it was just a quick run...

Comment: @MarcB: You do realize that both are merely wrappers on top of `mail()`, right? Also, congrats for 160k :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: actually, they're not. they will contact arbitrary smtp servers. mail() will only do that on windows machines. On unix-ish systems, you're stuck with the local mta only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`</tilte>` is spelled wrong in the head.
Should be `</title>`

Comment: You sir are my hero. Thanks, it worked. Stupid that it doesn't work with this "tiny" error...

Answer (score 1):

Unclear.  Looking at your HTML with carriage returns properly set:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor website.nl</tilte>
</head>
<body>
<p>Beste klant van website.nl,</p>
<p>website.nl is overgegaan naar een nieuw systeem en uw account is mee verhuisd. Helaas konden we niet uw oude wachtwoord gebruiken, aangezien die beveiligd was opgeslagen. Daarom waren wij genoodzaakt om uw wachtwoord te resetten.</p>
<p>Uw nieuwe gegevens zijn:<br />Email: ' . $leEmail . '<br />Wachtwoord: ' . $password . '</p>
<p>U kunt uw gegevens <a href="http://wwww,website.nl/index.php?route=account/account"> hier </a> na lopen en desnoods veranderen.</p>
<p>Mochten er nog vragen / opmerkingen zijn, dan horen wij dat graag.</p>
<p>Met Vriendelijke Groet,<br />Webbeheer website.nl</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder about this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

My gut says it should close itself so it should be; note the `/` at the end of the line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

**EDIT:** Looking at your core code this seems like another issue:

```
$headers .= 'To: email@addres.nl\r\n';
$headers .= 'From: Webmaster website.nl <webmaster@website.nl> \r\n';
```

Perhaps try it like this.

```
$headers .= "To: " . 'email@addres.nl' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: " . 'Webmaster website.nl <webmaster@website.nl>' . "\r\n";
```

The single versus double quote issue could be adding more lines to the message body & thus have your mail program choke when trying to process the HTML part of the message.  Meaning it seems like that the one line space between the headers & the body cause issues. So what looks like this; look at the area between `Subject:` and the body of the message:

```
Subject: Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor website.nl 

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor website.nl</tilte></head><body><p>Beste klant van website.nl,</p><p>website.nl is overgegaan naar een nieuw systeem en uw account is mee verhuisd. Helaas konden we niet uw oude wachtwoord gebruiken, aangezien die beveiligd was opgeslagen. Daarom waren wij genoodzaakt om uw wachtwoord te resetten.</p><p>Uw nieuwe gegevens zijn:<br />Email: email@addres.nl<br />Wachtwoord: 55jws2tS0j</p><p>U kunt uw gegevens <a href="http://wwww,website.nl/index.php?route=account/account"> hier </a> na lopen en desnoods veranderen.</p><p>Mochten er nog vragen / opmerkingen zijn, dan horen wij dat graag.</p><p>Met Vriendelijke Groet,<br />Webbeheer website.nl</p></body></html>
```

Should render like this:

```
Subject: Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor website.nl
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Uw nieuwe aanmeld gegevens voor website.nl</tilte></head><body><p>Beste klant van website.nl,</p><p>website.nl is overgegaan naar een nieuw systeem en uw account is mee verhuisd. Helaas konden we niet uw oude wachtwoord gebruiken, aangezien die beveiligd was opgeslagen. Daarom waren wij genoodzaakt om uw wachtwoord te resetten.</p><p>Uw nieuwe gegevens zijn:<br />Email: email@addres.nl<br />Wachtwoord: 55jws2tS0j</p><p>U kunt uw gegevens <a href="http://wwww,website.nl/index.php?route=account/account"> hier </a> na lopen en desnoods veranderen.</p><p>Mochten er nog vragen / opmerkingen zijn, dan horen wij dat graag.</p><p>Met Vriendelijke Groet,<br />Webbeheer website.nl</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed that but didn't help :S

Comment: Thank you for the idea's. luckly it did render nice now, but i just use this because you never know ;)